# Apply class to body while watching videos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to first check if the browser is webkit or not, and then apply a class to the body when a user clicks on a video to play it? If the browser is webkit, I'd like to apply the class .blur, and if the browser is not webkit, i'd like to add a dark overlay, so the user can focus on the video. I would have NO clue whatsoever how to do this except for apply the blur, hehe. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.body.className += ' blur';
}
```

Comment: Like I said this is good, but I still need the whole when a user clicks on a video thing...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) that provides you information on the browser that is accessing the page, including rendering engine.

As for detecting when the user plays the video, that depends on how your video is embedded.  If you're using HTML5 and use the `<video>` tag, HTML5 provides events for things like play, pause, seek, etc.  See here: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the navigator.userAgent value to check.like:

```
var UA = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
function testWebkit(){
    if(/webkit/i.test(UA))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```